# How to "compare" vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, vectors

I'm reading the definition of matrix norm in Golub & Van Loan and came across this 
"It is clear that the p-norm of matrix A is the p-norm of **the largest vector** obtained by applying A to a unit p-norm vector"

My question is how to know which vector is the largest? Is it the length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of norms, the "largest" is going to be the norm of greatest numerical value. If you're using the Euclidean norm, this "largest value" is going to correspond to length. For $p$-norm vectors, this isn't the case (you can still call the magnitude "length", but it doesn't correspond to the same notion of length we think about in the real world). In symbols, the norm of the matrix is
$$\|A\|_p = \sup\{\|Ax\|_p: \|x\|_p = 1\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

What is meant there is largest vector as defined  by the $p$-norm of the vector. It is in  some sense a notion of length, too. However it is not (in general) the usual euclidean notion of length, that would be the $2$-norm/euclidean norm.